# Time Complexity of a Union Find algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, union-find

I'm trying to understand the time complexity of an example algorithm. My conclusion was O(n^2) but this was considered wrong. The algorithm is as follows:

input: data: array of sorted n integers

input: n: size of data

input: c:a positive integer between 1 and n-1


delta = Array(n-1)

map=HashMap()

for I =1 to n-1 do:

delta[i] = data[i+1] - data[i]

map.Insert(delta[I],i)

end

heap=MinHeap(delta)

uf = UnionFind(n)

for I =1 to c do:

t=heap.deleteMin()

x=map.Search()

uf.Union(x,x+1)

end

return uf

To my knowledge
the first for loop runs in O(n) time, building the heap takes O(n), and the second for loop would run at O(n^2) times dominating the other complexities.

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out. Since uf.Union is an inverse ackermann it grows so slowly that it could be considered constant. thus the second loop would run O(c*lgn) giving and expected output of O(n + c*lg n))